# How to export existing keys from ProtectToolKit 7 (Thales) and import them to AWS CloudHSM?

Tags: encryption, hardware-security-module, amazon-cloudhsm

I have an existing system that uses HSM and Thales ProtectToolKit 7 (HSM Client) on-premises and would like to migrate it to AWS CloudHSM. How can I export existing keys from Thales ProtectToolKit 7 and import them into AWS CloudHSM?

I have already attempted to use a Wrapping Key to wrap existing keys into a file, but it appears that AWS doesn't support a Wrapping Key that has multiple key components